# How to use Laravel Socialite with Laravel Spark

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

**Is it possible to use Laravel Spark on a site where logins are controlled via Laravel Socialite?**  The documentation doesn't make this immediately clear to me.  I understand I wouldn't be able to utilize the 2-factor authentication.  Without access to the source code I can't scope out the difficulty, so I'm hoping someone who's used it can assist in answering this.

Comment: [Laracast forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/spark/integrating-socialite-with-spark) `The answer is no, not really lol. I just used LoginController to control all the Socialite stuff, updated my routes, job done.` but that's 1 year ago .. not sure about now .. good luck anyway.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @JamieRoss The latest

Answer (score 2):

**First**

Laravel Spark is not meant something to integrate with an existing project. Its something to start with it, which save your time so don't 've to integrate common things and quickly implement / integrate / enhance your custom business / application requirements. Visit https://spark.laravel.com/ to check what you'll get ready made when start with Spark.

Here's what the official website says.

> Spark provides the perfect starting point for your next big idea.
>   Forget all the boilerplate and focus on what matters: your application

**Second**

Spark is not free, You need to buy subscription key "Spark API token" which will lead you to install / use speak and start modify that for your business needs.

**However**

If your application already build on Spark and you are looking for features that   offer by new version of spark, you might need to upgrade your Spark. You can check your Spark version by `php artisan spark:version command`

> Updating might break your application, you need to be always careful
>   and follow the official guide and do backup.

**Using Laravel Socialite with spark**

You should be able to integrate socialite on your laravel application build on spark if that's your application business case or application requirement like any other requirements. This might be tricky to enhance the spark authentication code or follow spark approach to implement features. If you are a paid customer of spark you can ask for support. And to scope out difficulty you can go through the **comments** of this post https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/spark/integrating-socialite-with-spark , it seems devs are already trying to integrate those.

**Spark and the 2-factor authentication issue**

I seems that spark latest version already integrate two factor authentication support. Here some text form official doc

> Spark makes it simple to offer two-factor authentication to your
>   users. Two-factor authentication provides your users additional
>   account security by requiring them to provide a token during login in
>   addition to their username and password. This token is generally
>   retrieved from an application or SMS on their cellphone. Read more on that https://spark.laravel.com/docs/6.0/two-factor

**Finally**

Here's a screencast for a quick overview of what Spark is https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-spark/episodes/1

Hope That Helps